# Improving error rate

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have $1000$ cars. Also suppose out of a random sample of $300$ cars, $1$ of them fail. So the failure rate is $1/300$. Now we have $700$ cars left. To improve the failure rate, what is the additional number of cars that need to be tested? What is the failure probability? Can we model this with a exponential distribution with rate $\lambda=1/300$?

Is there a way to improve the estimate of the failure rate?

Comment: Do you mean improve the estimate of the error failure rate?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: No I want to actually improve the failure rate (i.e. make it smaller).

Comment: You can't honestly do anything to "improve the failure rate," except figure out why you get failures and fix the problem. Any additionally sampling "until you get the failure rate you want" is bad statistics. Honest additional sampling can make your failure rate go up or down.

Answer (score 1):

No amount of testing will change the actual failure rate.  If you test $n$ more cars, and none fail, the observed failure rate will decrease to $1/(300+n)$  With only one observed failure, your confidence in the observed failure rate being close to the actual one is low.  You can model it with any distribution you like, but whether that is accurate enough or useful is another question.